# Layered rendering to 3D texture using glFrameBufferTextureLayer

Tags: javascript, webgl, rendering

My goal is to render slices to a 3D texture using `gl.frameBufferTextureLayer`. However, nothing gets rendered when I read back the data with `gl.readPixels`.

When I'm changing `gl.TEXTURE_3D`to `gl.TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY` it works fine, but in the tests [here](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/WebGL/blob/master/sdk/tests/conformance2/renderbuffers/framebuffer-texture-layer.html) they are certainly attaching a layer of a 3D texture to the FBO. The WebGL [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL2RenderingContext/framebufferTextureLayer) doesn't say anything about what texture should be, but 
GLES3 [docs](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.0/html/glFramebufferTextureLayer.xhtml) allows texture to be a 3D texture for sure. I've checked framebuffer complete status and all that stuff..

Are there any resources for attaching a 3D texture layer to a FBO in WebGL2, is this even possible? Some code:

```
this.fbo= gl.createFramebuffer();
gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, this.fbo);

this.colorTexture = gl.createTexture();
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_3D, this.colorTexture);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_3D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_3D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
gl.texImage3D(gl.TEXTURE_3D, 0, gl.RGBA8, 64, 64, 64, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);

this.renderBuffer = gl.createRenderbuffer();
gl.bindRenderbuffer(gl.RENDERBUFFER, this.renderBuffer);
gl.renderbufferStorage(gl.RENDERBUFFER, gl.DEPTH_COMPONENT16, 64, 64);    
gl.framebufferRenderbuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, gl.RENDERBUFFER, this.renderBuffer);

// Use level 1 in 3D texture
// Works when texture is GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY
gl.framebufferTextureLayer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, this.texture, 0, 1);

// ... Render scene

let data = new Uint8Array(64 * 64 * 4);
gl.readPixels(0, 0, 64, 64, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, data, 0); // data is empty
```

Answer (score 1):

First let's try a simple one no rendering

```js
const gl = document.createElement("canvas").getContext("webgl2");
const fb = gl.createFramebuffer();
gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, fb);

const tex = gl.createTexture();
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_3D, tex);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_3D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_3D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
gl.texImage3D(gl.TEXTURE_3D, 0, gl.RGBA8, 2, 2, 2, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);

gl.framebufferTextureLayer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, tex, 0, 1);

gl.clearColor(.25, .5, .75, 1);
gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

const data = new Uint8Array(2 * 2 * 4);
gl.readPixels(0, 0, 2, 2, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
console.log(data);
```

That works

Now let's try rendering

```js
const gl = document.createElement("canvas").getContext("webgl2");
const fb = gl.createFramebuffer();
gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, fb);

const tex = gl.createTexture();
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_3D, tex);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_3D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_3D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
gl.texImage3D(gl.TEXTURE_3D, 0, gl.RGBA8, 2, 2, 2, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);

gl.framebufferTextureLayer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, tex, 0, 1);

const vs = `
#version 300 es
void main() {
  gl_Position = vec4(0, 0, 0, 1);
  gl_PointSize = 4.0;
}
`;

const fs = `
#version 300 es
precision mediump float;
out vec4 color;
void main() {
  color = vec4(.75, .5, .25, 1);
}
`

const prg = twgl.createProgram(gl, [vs, fs]);
gl.useProgram(prg);
gl.viewport(0, 0, 2, 2);
gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, 1);

const data = new Uint8Array(2 * 2 * 4);
gl.readPixels(0, 0, 2, 2, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
console.log(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl.min.js"></script>
```

That works too.

Let's try with a depth buffer

```js
const gl = document.createElement("canvas").getContext("webgl2");
const fb = gl.createFramebuffer();
gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, fb);

const tex = gl.createTexture();
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_3D, tex);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_3D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_3D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
gl.texImage3D(gl.TEXTURE_3D, 0, gl.RGBA8, 2, 2, 2, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);

gl.framebufferTextureLayer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, tex, 0, 1);

const rb = gl.createRenderbuffer();
gl.bindRenderbuffer(gl.RENDERBUFFER, rb);
gl.renderbufferStorage(gl.RENDERBUFFER, gl.DEPTH_COMPONENT16, 2, 2);    
gl.framebufferRenderbuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, gl.RENDERBUFFER, rb);


const vs = `
#version 300 es
uniform float depth;
void main() {
  gl_Position = vec4(0, 0, depth, 1);
  gl_PointSize = 4.0;
}
`;

const fs = `
#version 300 es
precision mediump float;
uniform vec4 color;
out vec4 outColor;
void main() {
  outColor = color;
}
`

const prgInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [vs, fs]);
gl.useProgram(prgInfo.program);
gl.viewport(0, 0, 2, 2);
gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);

// draw in middle
twgl.setUniforms(prgInfo, {
  depth: 0,
  color: [1, 0, 0, 1],
});
gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, 1);


// draw in front
twgl.setUniforms(prgInfo, {
  depth: -.5,
  color: [0, 1, 0, 1],
});
gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, 1);

// draw in back
twgl.setUniforms(prgInfo, {
  depth: .5,
  color: [0, 0, 1, 1],
});
gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, 1);

// should be front color (0, 255, 0, 255)

const data = new Uint8Array(2 * 2 * 4);
gl.readPixels(0, 0, 2, 2, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
console.log(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl.min.js"></script>
```

Seems to work

Maybe you're forgetting to set the viewport? I make that mistake often

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work indeed.. Can you explain why the last example doesn't pass the depth test?

Comment: The last example is passing the depth test for me (updated sample to test). Is it not working for you?

Comment: Weird, the last example is all 0's for me. Tested in latest Chrome and Firefox on a GTX 1070

Comment: Can confirm that it works on my Macbook Pro. Driver bug? :o

Comment: Filed a bug: https://github.com/KhronosGroup/WebGL/issues/2618. Please add any info like your OS, version, GPU etc.